# цикл for пропускает инициализацию первого элемента массива

Tags: java, массивы, for, инициализация

При первом цикле в for не инициализируется значение первого элемента массива, пропускается, а с последующего цикла - всё работает корректно
Код метода:

```
private void set() {
        System.out.print("Введите количество квартир: ");
        n=in.nextInt();
        apartments = new String[n];
        System.out.println("Введите квартиры:");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            String str;
            str=in.nextLine();
            apartments[i]=str;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Вывод:

Введите количество квартир: 3
Введите квартиры:
0
0
1
sdgfsdg
1
2
sdgsdgsdg
2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    n = in.nextInt();
    apartments = new String[n];
    in.nextLine(); // !!!
```

`nextInt` не считывает конец строки, который у Вас считывался на первой итерации цикла.

Comment: Можно подробнее, а то не понял?(
Теперь понял: подставил - и заработало, но всё же: почему не работало? Чтобы потом не совершать такой ошибки

Comment: @podrojatel `nextInt` не считывает конец строки, который у Вас считывался на первой итерации цикла.

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо